# Errors while running clsurf

Tags: opencl, surf

I am trying to run the CLSurf code posted on http://code.google.com/p/clsurf/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc
I have an ATI graphics card which supports OpenCL. I have also installed OpenCV.
I put the path directories of both OpenCL (AMD SDK) and OpenCV. 
But when I run the program the following errors occur. I am at loss and cant understand.

main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl surfRef(char *,int,int,int,float,void * *)" (?surfRef@@YAHPADHHHMPAPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl mainImage(struct _cl_kernel * *,char *,char *,char *,bool)" (?mainImage@@YAHPAPAU_cl_kernel@@PAD11_N@Z)
1>C:\Users\RohitRP\Documents\AMD APP\\samples\opencl\bin\debug\x86\openclsurf.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I know there are lot of errors out here. But since it is posted on code.google.com I am assuming it has to be the right code and it is my mistake. I would really appreciate someone helping me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "run" you really mean "compile" don't you - those are Visual Studio linking errors you are posting, are they not?

Comment: yes it is visual studio linking errors while compiling the program

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, clSurf is currently implemented and running on Linux, have you ported this to Windows to make it run using Visual Studio ? Have you checked below wiki http://code.google.com/p/clsurf/source/browse/wiki/InstallationLinux.wiki

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is nothing in clsurf that is really Windows or Linux specific

The problem is the function call to "surfRef" which is used to call the baseline serial SURF implementation that you can link to. We used the serial baseline to compare our code against.

http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html

The C++ baseline is not included in the OpenCL code since its not needed and also not created by us. You could simply comment out the "if(verifyResults)" block or the function call on line 300 in main.cpp

I should have added a macro around it to disable it if verification isnt required. Sorry about that.